# Do not record particular page hit

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am trying to hit particular web page and record post its load for example:
`http://serv1.project.com/page7`

but on hitting above page only `http://serv1.project.com` gets recorded. When i play same script then `http://serv1.project.com` is opened without subsequent page hit.

Note: I am trying to run my scripts using RC with java as base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does it matter what gets recorded? Can't you just do:

```
selenium.open("page7");
```

in your Java code?

Of course I assume you have created the selenium session with the http://serv1.project.com/ as a base URL.